# In Azure Devops how to get all the Pull Requests between 2 branches

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

We have a development branch and a staging branch. Development is 100 commits ahead of staging.

How do I get the list of pull requests related to those commits?

On the devops UI this is the URL: https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repo/branchCompare?baseVersion=staging&targetVersion=GBdevelopment&_a=commits

Here a picture of what I would like.

[image]

What I've tried (in Powershell)

```
$uriCompare = $UriOrga + "_apis/git/repositories/aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee/diffs/commits?baseVersion="+$baseVersion+"&targetVersion="+$targetVersion+"&api-version=6.0"
$compare = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriCompare -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
```

I get a list of objects that look like this

```
 @ {
    objectId = asdfghjkl12345678fghjklcvbnmsfghjk123456;
    originalObjectId = 123456asdfghjklwertyui4567dfrgthyjk67jk1;
    gitObjectType = blob;
    commitId = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345678901234;
    path = /path1/path2/file.txt;
    url = https: //dev.azure.com/org/abcdefgg-1234-abcd-addd-eeeeeeeeeeee/_apis/git/repositories/aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee/items/path1/path2/file.sql?versionType=Commit&version=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345678901234
    }
```

They all have the same commit ID.